# Jewish Captivity

Tags: john

Is John forgetting the Jewish captivity in Babylon?

**John 8:33 KJV**

> They answered him, We be Abraham's seed, and were never in bondage to any man: how sayest thou, Ye shall be made free?

Comment: I answered this question [here](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8445/why-do-the-jews-in-john-833-say-that-they-have-never-been-enslaved) so I won't repeat it. It follows in line w/ScottS's answer.